# Xamarin Android BroadcastReceiver triggers as many times as alarms I have schedule

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have an android application where I use the AlarmManager to schedule some recurring alarms, also I have an intent and a broadcast receiver so when the alarm trigger it will execute the broadcast receiver.

here is how I set the alarm

```
    static Calendar GenerateSchedule(int Hour, int Minute)
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);
        Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);
        alarmTime.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, Hour);
        alarmTime.Set(CalendarField.Minute, Minute);
        alarmTime.Set(CalendarField.Second, 0);
        alarmTime.Set(CalendarField.Millisecond, 0);

        return alarmTime;

    }
    public static void AddAlarm(int Id, int hour, int Minute)
    {

        var Manager = (AlarmManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AlarmNotificationReceiver));
        AlarmIntent.PutExtra("Id", Id);           
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Id, AlarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        if (pendingIntent != null)
        {
            Calendar Schedule = GenerateSchedule(hour, Minute);

            Manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, Schedule.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalDay, pendingIntent);

        }

    }
```

here is the call to the AddAlarm

```
AddAlarm(0, 5, 30);
AddAlarm(1, 6, 30);
AddAlarm(2, 7, 30);
AddAlarm(3, 8, 30);
AddAlarm(4, 9, 30);
```

and here is the broadcastreceiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "THIS IS MY ALARM", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

So using the code above I set up 5 alarms at different times of the day.

What I expect is that my broadcast receiver will trigger 1 time per each alarm but actually every time the any of the 5 alarms trigger the broadcast receiver execute as many times as alarms I have schedule, so in this case it triggers 5 times.

Should I do any special code to on the BroadcastReceiver to handle this situation? or am I scheduling the alarms in the wrong way?

Comment: The codes is not complete, could you please provide the codes of `GenerateSchedule(hour,minute)` and the codes  where `AddAlarm` get called?

Comment: Done I have  updated my post with the missing info

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, could you please try it on other device/emulator? If the issue persists, could you pls share a basic sample?